# Scrapy can't export bodytext

Tags: python, scrapy

So I'm trying to work with a Scrapy project called [RISJbot](https://github.com/pmyteh/RISJbot) for extracting the contents of news articles for my research, however I encountered a problem that I can't find the source of, or the way to fix it: the spider doesn't really return body texts (couldn't find any on the Washington Post, and few on CNN), which would be very important in the case of an article.

I'm not very familiar with Python, but from what I understand, it makes several attempts to find the bodytext, and when it fails to do so, it returns a gzipped and Base 64-encoded version.

What would you recommend me to do? I couldn't find a way so far to fix it.

Here's the spider itself:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from RISJbot.spiders.newssitemapspider import NewsSitemapSpider
from RISJbot.loaders import NewsLoader
# Note: mutate_selector_del_xpath is somewhat naughty. Read its docstring.
from RISJbot.utils import mutate_selector_del_xpath
from scrapy.loader.processors import Identity, TakeFirst
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join, Compose, MapCompose
import re

class WashingtonPostSpider(NewsSitemapSpider):
    name = 'washingtonpost'
    # allowed_domains = ['washingtonpost.com']
    # A list of XML sitemap files, or suitable robots.txt files with pointers.
    sitemap_urls = ['https://www.washingtonpost.com/news-sitemaps/index.xml']

    def parse_page(self, response):
        """@url http://www.washingtonpost.com/business/2019/10/25/us-deficit-hit-billion-marking-nearly-percent-increase-during-trump-era/?hpid=hp_hp-top-table-main_deficit-210pm%3Ahomepage%2Fstory-ans
        @returns items 1
        @scrapes bodytext bylines fetchtime firstpubtime headline source url 
        @noscrapes modtime
        """
        s = response.selector
        # Remove any content from the tree before passing it to the loader.
        # There aren't native scrapy loader/selector methods for this.        
        #mutate_selector_del_xpath(s, '//*[@style="display:none"]')

        l = NewsLoader(selector=s)

        # WaPo's ISO date/time strings are invalid: <datetime>-500 instead of
        # <datetime>-05:00. Note that the various standardised l.add_* methods
        # will generate 'Failed to parse data' log items. We've got it properly
        # here, so they aren't important.
        l.add_xpath('firstpubtime',
                    '//*[@itemprop="datePublished" or '
                        '@property="datePublished"]/@content',
                    MapCompose(self.fix_iso_date)) # CreativeWork

        # These are duplicated in the markup, so uniquise them.
        l.add_xpath('bylines',
                    '//div[@itemprop="author-names"]/span/text()',
                    set)
        l.add_xpath('section',
                    '//*[contains(@class, "headline-kicker")]//text()')


        # Add a number of items of data that should be standardised across
        # providers. Can override these (for TakeFirst() fields) by making
        # l.add_* calls above this line, or supplement gaps by making them
        # below.
        l.add_fromresponse(response)
        l.add_htmlmeta()
        l.add_schemaorg(response)
        l.add_opengraph()
        l.add_scrapymeta(response)

        return l.load_item()

    def fix_iso_date(self, s):
        return re.sub(r'^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[+-])'
                            '([0-9])([0-9]{2})$',
                      r'\g<1>0\g<2>:\g<3>',
                      s)
```

The full error message is (it doesn't have a "Traceback" part):

> ERROR:RISJbot.pipelines.checkcontent:No bodytext: https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/europe/russia-and-cuba-rebuild-ties-that-frayed-after-cold-war/2019/10/29/d046cc0a-fa09-11e9-9e02-1d45cb3dfa8f_story.html

I also found another error, although I'm not sure if it's linked to the bodytext issue:

> ERROR:scrapy.utils.signal:Error caught on signal handler: >
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\sigalizer\Anaconda3\envs\scrapyenv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 151, in maybeDeferred
>       result = f(*args, **kw)
>     File "C:\Users\sigalizer\Anaconda3\envs\scrapyenv\lib\site-packages\pydispatch\robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
>       return receiver(*arguments, **named)
>     File "C:\Users\sigalizer\Anaconda3\envs\scrapyenv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\extensions\feedexport.py", line 243, in item_scraped
>       slot = self.slot
>   AttributeError: 'FeedExporter' object has no attribute 'slot'

Comment: first I would check if page doesn't use JavaScript to add text. Scrapy doesn't run JavaScript. It would need `Selenium` to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure, could you confirm it?

Comment: you can turn off javascript in browser and then load page in browser to see if it shows expected item.

Comment: Checked it, it loads the page perfectly, only with low-res images (and there might be other elements missing, but certainly not the bodytext).

Comment: What do you mean about the spider not returning bodies? Is `response.text` an empty string or `None`?

Comment: When I run the spider, it says it couldn't find bodytext. Then it fills it up with a series of numbers, letters, and symbols, which I assume is a gzipped and Base 64-encoded text, because I saw references to that in the `loaders.py`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Apologies, error added.